# Python fitting a curve with coeficents errors

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, coefficients, uncertainty

I need to fit a curve over a set of data and also need the uncertainty - or errors - of the coefficients, for exemple:

fitting a*x^2+b*x+c, i need the values: a+-da, b+-db and c+-dc. Where da,db and dc are the uncertaints.

I already tried polyfit and optmize.curve_fit, but none of them give me de uncertainty as I want. Some one knows how to do that?

Comment: `optmize.curve_fit` returns the estimated covariances. The diagonal provides the variance of the parameter estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that works for both linear and nonlinear fitting and should be useful:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import scipy.odr
import scipy.stats

x = np.array([5.357, 5.797, 5.936, 6.161, 6.697, 6.731, 6.775, 8.442, 9.861])
y = np.array([0.376, 0.874, 1.049, 1.327, 2.054, 2.077, 2.138, 4.744, 7.104])

def f(x,b0,b1):
    return b0 + (b1 * x)


def f_wrapper_for_odr(beta, x): # parameter order for odr
    return f(x, *beta)

parameters, cov= curve_fit(f, x, y)

model = scipy.odr.odrpack.Model(f_wrapper_for_odr)
data = scipy.odr.odrpack.Data(x,y)
myodr = scipy.odr.odrpack.ODR(data, model, beta0=parameters,  maxit=0)
myodr.set_job(fit_type=2)
parameterStatistics = myodr.run()
df_e = len(x) - len(parameters) # degrees of freedom, error
cov_beta = parameterStatistics.cov_beta # parameter covariance matrix from ODR
sd_beta = parameterStatistics.sd_beta * parameterStatistics.sd_beta
ci = []
t_df = scipy.stats.t.ppf(0.975, df_e)
ci = []
for i in range(len(parameters)):
    ci.append([parameters[i] - t_df * parameterStatistics.sd_beta[i], parameters[i] + t_df * parameterStatistics.sd_beta[i]])

tstat_beta = parameters / parameterStatistics.sd_beta # coeff t-statistics
pstat_beta = (1.0 - scipy.stats.t.cdf(np.abs(tstat_beta), df_e)) * 2.0    # coef. p-values

for i in range(len(parameters)):
    print('parameter:', parameters[i])
    print('   conf interval:', ci[i][0], ci[i][1])
    print('   tstat:', tstat_beta[i])
    print('   pstat:', pstat_beta[i])
    print()
```